# Understanding Serial Data from XBee using Node-XBee and Node-SerialPort

Tags: node.js, arduino, xbee, node-serialport, node-xbee

`node-serialport` and `node-xbee` are used in the following code to read incoming XBee frames from a XBee Series 2 in Router AT configuration. A potentiometer is connected to pin 20 `AD0` analog input pin of the XBee. All 4 analog pins `AD0`, `AD1`, `AD2`, `AD3` are enabled, only `AD1` is connected to something.

How do you interpret the `data` array in the `frame_object` received? Theres obviously a trend here, when 0V is fed to the XBee, we receive a array `data` ending with elements `0, 0, 2, 14, 2, 8, 2, 15`. When 3.3V is fed to the XBee, the `data` array ends with elements `3, 255, 3, 255, 3, 255, 3, 255`.

How do you convert these raw values to something more meaningful? `3, 255` looks like a pair of values that denote 3.3V? But how do we get from `3, 255` to a voltage reading?

**Reading serial port data**

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport').SerialPort;
var xbee_api = require('xbee-api');

var C = xbee_api.constants;

var xbeeAPI = new xbee_api.XBeeAPI({
  api_mode: 1
});

var serialport = new SerialPort("/dev/cu.usbserial-A702NY8S", {
  baudrate: 9600,
  parser: xbeeAPI.rawParser()
});

xbeeAPI.on("frame_object", function(frame) {
  console.log("OBJ> "+util.inspect(frame));
});
```

**XBee Frames when XBee pin is fed 0V**

```
OBJ> { type: 145,
  remote64: '0013a20040b19213',
  remote16: '56bc',
  receiveOptions: 232,
  data: [ 232, 0, 146, 193, 5, 1, 1, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 2, 14, 2, 8, 2, 15 ] }

OBJ> { type: 145,
  remote64: '0013a20040b19213',
  remote16: '56bc',
  receiveOptions: 232,
  data: [ 232, 0, 146, 193, 5, 1, 1, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 2, 16, 2, 14, 2, 14 ] }

OBJ> { type: 145,
  remote64: '0013a20040b19213',
  remote16: '56bc',
  receiveOptions: 232,
  data: [ 232, 0, 146, 193, 5, 1, 1, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 2, 17, 2, 11, 2, 9 ] }
```

**XBee Frames when XBee pin is fed 3.3V**

```
OBJ> { type: 145,
  remote64: '0013a20040b19213',
  remote16: '56bc',
  receiveOptions: 232,
  data: [ 232, 0, 146, 193, 5, 1, 1, 0, 0, 15, 3, 255, 3, 255, 3, 255, 3, 255 ] }

OBJ> { type: 145,
  remote64: '0013a20040b19213',
  remote16: '56bc',
  receiveOptions: 232,
  data: [ 232, 0, 146, 193, 5, 1, 1, 0, 0, 15, 3, 255, 3, 255, 3, 255, 3, 255 ] }

OBJ> { type: 145,
  remote64: '0013a20040b19213',
  remote16: '56bc',
  receiveOptions: 232,
  data: [ 232, 0, 146, 193, 5, 1, 1, 0, 0, 15, 3, 255, 3, 255, 3, 255, 3, 255 ] }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documentation for the format of an `ATIS` response.

Header bytes include the endpoint (232 = 0xE8) and cluster (193, 5 = 0xC105) for the frame.  I'm not sure about the 0, 145 and extra 1 before the input sample.  I think the bytes after `5, 1` decode as follows:

Starts with an 8-bit sample count (0x01).

Then a 16-bit reading of enabled digital inputs (0x0000).

Then an 8-bit reading of enabled analog inputs (0x0F).

If there were any enabled digital inputs, you'd have a 16-bit value for all digital readings.

The four analog inputs follow (`3, 255` = 0x03FF), and they're a scaled 10-bit value.

```
reference voltage * reading / 0x03FF
```

So, in your case, `3.3V * 0x03FF / 0x03FF = 3.3V`.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the data you could do the following

```
 xbeeAPI.on("frame_object", function (frame) {
             console.log("OBJ> " + frame);
             console.log("OBJ> " + util.inspect(frame));
             console.log("Data> " + util.inspect(frame.data.toString()));
```